# Gem installing an old version of Neat

Tags: bourbon, neat, thoughtbot

Trying to install bourbon neat 2.0 and cannot get current version to install. Running the commands to install to directory `gem install neat` followed by `neat install` and all appears normal. Messages even says "fetching 2.0.0" etc, however once installed the files appear to be from version `1.7.2`

**Commands and messages for install**

[image: neat-install]

**Files that show up post install**

[image: old-neat]

What am I possibly messing up here lol.
Thank you.